# Mongodb: how to perform subqueries?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have documents which further have arrays. I want to query an array returned as a result of a previous query.
For example I have

```
{
{_id : 001,
 data: [{
        value: 1,
        name: 'Roger'
       },
       {value: 2,
        name: 'Albert'
       },
       {value: 3,
        name: 'Allen'
       }]
},
{_id: 002,
data: [{value: 4,
        name: 'Allison'
       },
       {value: 5,
        name: 'Tom'
       }]
}
}
```

I can get document where _id is equal to 001 but I want to query it's **data** field where value is equal to 2 and 3. I don't know what is the solution for that. In SQL It could be performed with **Sub-queries** but I don't know how to do it in mongodb.

Comment: To be clear, do you mean you only want to get the matching elements of the `data` array where `value` is 2 and 3 ?  If so, see the Aggregation Framework example on: [extract only the selected item in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214).

Comment: Yes absolutely I want to get only matching elements of 'data' array. Because mongodb only returns a single document therefore I'm having this problem. So aggregation is the solution?

Comment: Yes, you'll be best using Aggregation Framework if you only want the MongoDB server to return the matching `data` array elements rather than the whole `data` arrays.

Comment: @Stennie I'm querying this collection as
    'db.sample.find({}, {_id:0, data:{$elemMatch: value:{$gt:1, $lte:3}}})'
but It only returns a single element of data array. Kindly help

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I'm going to have a look on aggregation framework now. Actually I have data array having hundreds of elements so I want to get only matching elements on the basis of my query. Regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use $elemMatch: 
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

a good example:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/all/

```
1.db.test.save({d: [{k1:1, v1:1}]}) 
2.db.test.save({d: [{k1:1, v1:1}]}) 
3.db.test.find({d:{$elemMatch:{k1:1}}})
```

return:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52aea61c54125a39453c8836"), "d" : [ { "k1" : 1, "v1" : 1 } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52aea62054125a39453c8837"), "d" : [ { "k1" : 1, "v1" : 1 } ] }
```

Note that $elemMatch query is different from $elemMatch projection.

Comment: The [`$elemMatch` projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) only returns the first matching array element.  This use case is to return multiple matching elements, so the best server-side option (as at MongoDB 2.4) would be to use the Aggregation Framework.

Comment: Yes this is my problem because $elemMatch only returns first matching element but I want to get multiple elements

Comment: But what I said was "$elemMatch Query", not projection.

Comment: 1.db.test.save({d: [{k1:1, v1:1}]})  2.db.test.save({d: [{k1:1, v1:1}]})  3.db.test.find({d:{$elemMatch:{k1:1}}})  All the two records will be returned.

Comment: Thanks for helping, I used $elemMatch Query also but possibly you took me wrong. I don't want to get multiple records, I want to get a single record which further has a field and that field has array. I want to query those array elements and get them. I posted my problem above and lets suppose I want to get document where _id is equal to 001 and now I want to query data array and want to get only matching elements of that array. Hope you can help now

Answer (score 0):

## Inserted 2 records in 2 different collections for join :

```
> db.employee.insert({eid:1,name:"premaseem"})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
> db.salary.insert({ eid:1, salary:6000 })
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
```

## Validated data in 2 tables :

```
> db.salary.find({ eid:1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56da1a5b2253b2199c53025b"), "eid" : 1, "salary" : 6000 }
> db.salary.find({ eid: db.employee.find({eid:1})  })
> db.employee.find({name : "prem" })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("56da19d42253b2199c53025a"), "eid" : 1, "name" : "prem" }
```

## simulated join to get salary for employee premaseem :

```
> db.employee.find({name : "premaseem" }).map(function(d){  var obj =  db.salary.findOne({eid : d.eid  }); print(obj.salary)  }  )
6000
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked. There is data in the question and it is not asking to "join" data from two tables in any way.